# Upside down orientation of containerView

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I am making multiplayer mode for a game and want that screen should divide in to parts such that one is upside down... I have used container views but how to make it upside down the other...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe try to apply a transform on your container view. Like

```
containerView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, M_PI);
```

The transform is also applied to the touch events so it won't be a problem. You can create your view like any other view and just rotate it.